# WiFi not working after installing Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04, atheros

This is the first time I am installing a Linux machine.

I did a fresh install on my ACER ASPIRE ES, earlier it was Windows 8, and WiFi was working fine.

Then I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 17.04 by formatting the disk. Now the WiFi won't turn up. I tried a few things from the forum, but without luck.
Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Please help as I am spending sleepless nights on fixing this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I added the output as an image. sorry but not able to copy paste text

Answer (score 0):

Look for a hardware switch, reset BIOS to defaults, if it doesn't help run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: Woo Hoooo!! that fixed it. thanks buddy. whoever you are, wherever you are, God bless you

Comment: ONe last question. how do i install visual drivers in Ubuntu? the graphics look of very poor quality

Comment: This is not the right place to ask. You can ask another question.